# Comparing two attributes in one expression

Tags: lightning-aura-components, expressions

I am experiencing something strange, but I suspect I am doing something wrong

I have two string `aura:attributes`. When I try to compare them, the comparison doesn't work. Here is an example

**Component**

```
<aura:component description="BookATourButtons">
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="stepNumber"/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="maxSteps"/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="doNavigation" type="c:BookATourBeforeNavigate"/>

    {!v.stepNumber} -- {!v.maxSteps}
    equals : {!v.stepNumber == v.maxSteps}
</aura:component>
```

**Usage**
Parameters are being passed from parent component:

```
<c:BookATourButtons stepNumber="{!v.stepNumber}" maxSteps="{!v.maxStepNumber}"/>
```

**Examples**

If I pass the number '1' on both parameters, the output is

> 1 -- 1 equals : false

If I change the second expression to `{!v.stepNumber == '1'}`, then I correctly get

> 1 -- 1 equals : true

Changing the calling param to `<c:BookATourButtons stepNumber="{!v.stepNumber}" maxSteps="1"/>` also works

> 1 -- 1 equals : true

I suspect the comparison fails because both strings are treated like objects, but I can't figure out how to get around that.

PS: I've tried using other operators like `equals` and `eq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the answer, but would help us determine the behaviour.

I tried your code, and defaulted both attributes as String.

**Case 1:**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="stepNumber" default="1"/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="maxSteps" default="1"/>



    {!v.stepNumber} -- {!v.maxSteps}
    equals : {!v.stepNumber == v.maxSteps}
    <hr></hr>
    {!v.stepNumber == '1'}
</aura:application>
```

The OP:

```
1 -- 1 equals : true
--------------------------------
true
```

**Case 2:** I converted stepNumber as **Integer** or **Decimal**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="Integer" name="stepNumber" default="1"/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="maxSteps" default="1"/>



    {!v.stepNumber} -- {!v.maxSteps}
    equals : {!v.stepNumber == v.maxSteps}
    <hr></hr>
    {!v.stepNumber == '1'}
</aura:application>
```

The output :

```
1 -- 1 equals : false
---------------------
false
```

Based on this behaviour, we can deduce that datatype of stepNumberis changed in between.

Comment: It's not exactly what I did, but this helped me figure out that the problem was in the datatype coming from the database.